# How to calculate the difference between row values based on another column value without filtering the values in between

Tags: pandas

How to calculate the difference between row values based on another column value  without filtering the values in between.I want to calculate the difference between seconds for turn_marker == 1. but when I use the following method, it filters all the zeros but I need the zeros, because I need the entire data set.

[Here you can see my data set with a column called turn_marker that has the values zero and 1, and another column with seconds. Now I want to calculte the time bwetween those rows where turn_marker is equal 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4oDt.png)

```
dataframe = main_dataframe.query("turn_marker=='1;'")
main_dataframe["seconds_diff"] = dataframe["seconds"].diff()

main_dataframe
```

I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
main_dataframe['indx'] = main_dataframe.index
main_dataframe['diff'] = main_dataframe.sort_values(by=['turn_marker', 'indx'], ascending=[False, True])['seconds'].diff()
main_dataframe.loc[main_dataframe.turn_marker == '0;', 'diff'] = np.nan
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont want to sort the rows because i would then assign other values to the rows with turn_marker == 0 between the rows. You know what I mean? I want them to stay where they are

Comment: @ttask also vscode crashes when i run what you sent me

Comment: @Mahi you are sorting only temporarily in the snippet I provided. Order is maintained normally. Why does vscode crash? What is the error message? It probably has to do with the fact that I am using `df` instead of `main_dataframe`?

Comment: no actually, my data set is too large and takes too long for it to output something

Comment: like it takes for ever